# Como fazer upload no Silex?

Tags: php, upload, silex

Fiz algumas pesquisas para saber como fazer upload de arquivos no Silex Framework, porém não achei nada a respeito.

Existe algum meio de fazer isso através do Silex? Ou eu teria que fazer com *na unha* apenas com PHP?

Comment: Isso ajuda ? http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.0/providers/form.html

Comment: Hum, isso aí é o FormBuilder do Symfony. O formulário eu não preciso montar, já tenho pronto. Só preciso mesmo fazer o upload.

Comment: Na verdade, eu acho que eu estava boiando. Acho que a resposta é simples: É só fazer o upload igual faz no Symfony (que é quase a mesma coisa do Laravel)

Comment: O Silex não é micro-framework? Não seria melhor, então, usar PHP puro pra fazer o upload? https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Comment: Ele usa o core do symfony... Se já tem pronto, não faço na mão não.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O `Silex` usa os componentes do `Symfony`. Portanto, é possível utilizar o `Symfony Request` para poder fazer o upload.

Exemplo:

```
$app->post('/user/upload', function (Request $request) use ($app) {

     $upload = $request->files->get('arquivo');

});
```

No exemplo acima, se o arquivo for enviado, a variável `$upload` conterá uma instância de `UploadedFile`, caso seja enviado apenas um arquivo.

Então, você pode usar os métodos desse arquivo para fazer as operações desejadas.

Para mover o arquivo do upload, você usa o método `UploadedFile::move`.

Veja:

```
$upload->move($diretorio, $nome_do_arquivo);
```

Se você não informar `$nome_do_arquivo`, o arquivo receberá o nome que veio do formulário.

Você pode querer verificar o `mime` do arquivo. Para isso você pode usar o método `UploadedFile::getMimeType()`.

Ainda complementando, se você quiser saber qual é o nome do arquivo temporário do upload você deverá usar `UploadedFile::getRealPath()`.

Para saber o nome que veio do cliente você usa `UploadedFile::getClientOriginalName()`

Referências:

- [Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile](http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/UploadedFile.html)
- [Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request](http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.html)